# How to setup nginx configuration?

Tags: node.js, nginx, admin, backend

I have been trying to figure out how to point the server to my static page that i store it up somewhere in my cloud server. Also, i am using NodeJs as my backend.

My old problem: It's not point to my myProjectX index.html instead it points to the Nginx default web page "Welcome to Nginx!". I cannot figure out why ;/

Update

My new problem: After this new configuration that i did, it points me to a 404 page instead of pointing to my index.html

Also, in the line 20, it gives me an error of duplicate "/" when i run sudo nginx -t for debugging purpose

```
`nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:20 `
```

here's my Nginx configuration file...

```js
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name www.andii90s.com;

    root /home/andy/www/myProjectX/app;
    index index.html index.htm;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.137.10.140:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        #Line 20
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
       root /home/andy/www/myProjectX/app;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your configuration file is not being read *or* you didn't restart `nginx`.

Answer (score 5):

*refer this blog*
http://caffeinecodes.blogspot.in/2017/02/nginx-settings.html

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.com;
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location /static/ {
      alias /Users/Afxal/workspace/test_project/static/;
  }
  location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***First of all, restart your NGINX service***

```
service nginx restart
```

If this didn't do the trick,
Also check /etc/nginx/sites-available/ if you're using the default, if you created a new one it must be available in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/yourconfig /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

**If you want to run a website:**

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /home/andy/www/myProjectX/app;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name myUrl;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /home/andy/www/myProjectX/app;
}
```

**And, if you want to enable PHP just add this to your config file:**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

**If you want to use NGINX as a proxy for example a Node.js application use this:**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://hereip:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

This will make your application accessible on your root domain, for example: example.com. ;)

Comment: hi, i have include this line of code 
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

but it gives me a error that i have "/" duplicate somewhere...

Comment: it says right there in the error message what is wrong 'duplicate location'... You can't define the location '/' twice. Move the line you added into the existing block for '/'

Comment: What do you want, a static website using normal HTML/PHP etc. Or a webapp running on for example Node.js?

Comment: nginx will be handle static web page and nodeJs for dynamic content @Thom